# Gson custom byte[] handler

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I want byte[].class to JSON to B64. This has been done with the custom adapter.

However, when I run the `test()` code, it remains in B64 and does not turn back to byte[].

How to fix it?

```
public static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(byte[].class, new ByteArrayToBase64TypeAdapter()).create();

static class ByteArrayToBase64TypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<byte[]>, JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {

    public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement json, ProcessBuilder.Redirect.Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return Util.fromBase64(json.getAsString());
    }

    public JsonElement serialize(byte[] src, ProcessBuilder.Redirect.Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(Util.toBase64(src));
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(byte[] src, java.lang.reflect.Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(Util.toBase64(src));
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement json, java.lang.reflect.Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return Util.fromBase64(json.getAsString());
    }
}



private static void test(){
    ArrayList test = new ArrayList();
    test.add("hello");
    test.add("world".getBytes());

    final String json = Gson.gson.toJson(test);

    System.out.println("json: " + json);

    ArrayList from = Gson.gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList.class);
    System.out.println("from: " + from);
    for(int i = 0; i < from.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("i: " + i + "\tclass: " + from.get(i).getClass() + "\tvalue: " + from.get(i));
    }
}
```

The system outs:

```
json: ["hello","d29ybGQ\u003d"]
from: [hello, d29ybGQ=]
i: 0    class: class java.lang.String   value: hello
i: 1    class: class java.lang.String   value: d29ybGQ= //this should be in byte[].class
```

Comment: Overloads with `ProcessBuilder.Redirect.Type` are useless. Is it a typo?

Comment: Netbeans say must override, so I did.

Answer (score 1):

How would it know this specific JSON string happens to come from a `byte[]`? You need to specify it when decoding, e.g.

```
final byte[] bytes = "world".getBytes();
final String json = Gson.gson.toJson(bytes);
final byte[] bytes1 = Gson.gson.fromJson(json, byte[].class);
```

Or have a class with a `byte[]` field.

Comment: So I can't just put everything into a generic Container and turn it back to byte[]?

Comment: Sure, but 1) you need to use a proper generic container, e.g. `List<byte[]>`, not just raw `List` (which you should never use at any rate); 2) you still need to provide this information when deserializing using `TypeToken`s: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-arrays-and-lists-of-objects#datadeserializationofarrayslists.